# Excel: Sum up elements of a row if a certain element of a row is a particular name

Tags: vba, excel, sum, sumifs

My problem is depicted in this picture:
[image]

I want to sum up all ones of Alice, Bob and Carol – but I don’t know how to do this *without* a macro. Is it even possible to do this with a simple Excel formula (such as, e.g., `=SUMIF()`) so that the result is

- Alice: 8
- Bob: 8
- Carol: 12

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SUMPRODUCT`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumproduct-function) to sum a range based on criteria like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:G8)*(A2:A8="Alice"))
```

`(A2:A8="Alice")` will return `1` or `0` based on whether the criteria is`True` or `False`. Then, when multiplied by the range `(B2:G8)` only the values which meet the criteria will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Write (for Alice) the formula: `=SUM(IF(A:A="Alice";B:G))` (replace B:G for witch range you like to sum) and then press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. Your formula will appear like this `{=SUM(IF(A:A="Alice";B:G))}` and will return the value you want.